# MYSQL DB - New tables are created randomly

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My DB has increased in size very much, above 10GB.

I see these tables:

- emcxmp_wp_posts
- zjrqwg_wp_posts
- qtlmkn_wp_posts
- shcjpe_wp_posts
- stzbcj_wp_posts
- tymbkf_wp_posts
- ursnzw_wp_posts
- vkhjml_wp_posts
- oyjfup_wp_posts
- voxfcz_wp_posts
- xlhpaz_wp_posts
- ybazlk_wp_posts
- yjmify_wp_posts
- ymsaun_wp_posts
- yojkzl_wp_posts
- yqlfun_wp_posts
- wouevx_wp_posts
- msyfsp_wp_posts
- kqbjhz_wp_posts
- kqjsio_wp_posts
- lnfjsf_wp_posts
- asvpky_wp_posts
- bltyyt_wp_posts
- cyuhqr_wp_posts
- eudjso_wp_posts

And more, what happened and why these were created?

Comment: List of plugins you are using ?

Comment: A lot, some migration plugins, event calendar plugins... etc. What do yu have in mind?

Comment: He has in mind: please list all the plugins, as one of it will likely cause this issue, and he would like to have a look at this list. It's much easier for you to tell us your plugins than for us to tell you all plugins that might cause this. For example, your list may show the plugin "WP Reset Pro", and he would then say "Hey, that's probably the plugin that is causing this behaviour, please check if..." Or it may show a different plugin that may cause this behavior, and he would then say "Hey, that's probably the plugin that is causing this behaviour, please check if..."

Comment: I can find the plugin in question, I just need an explanation why some new tables are duplicated like that. Is this a common thing? Also, how to fix this? I tried to delete some of those tables and got a MSQL error connecting

Comment: Its not common thing and we dont have 3rd eye. Fix it by disable all of your plugins clear everything turn plugins one by one and observe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour of the plugin [WP Reset Pro](https://wpreset.com/).

It [creates snapshots](https://docs.wpreset.com/article/16-snapshots) with names as yours:

> - naming template for snapshot tables is {6_char_random_hex}*{table_prefix_for_your_site}*{original_table_name}

To [delete snapshots](https://docs.wpreset.com/article/22-delete-snapshot), use the appropriate function:

> If you do not need a specific snapshot on your WordPress site, you can quickly delete it:
>
> - Open Tools -> WP Reset -> Snapshots
> - Scroll down to the "User Created Snapshots" card
> - Select a snapshot & open the "Action" menu
> - Click "Delete snapshot"
> - Confirm that you want to delete it by clicking the red button

Comment: Thank you, yes I see this plugin in the list but I can't access dashbaord, any code I can run from the backend?

Comment: You may want to ask this on the [wordpress stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/); there are countless reasons why you cannot access the dashboard (if its an error, it's probably something you did trying to delete those tables; if it's just a forgotten password, they have a solution too), and there you might get more specialized help than here.